# Google apps script keep considering my calculation as string, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, operators

I got a code like this:

```
  var date = new Date(new Date() + dateAdjust*3600*1000 );
```

However, the result came out weird. But if I change the plus sign to a minus sign, and make the dateAdjust become negative, it results right. I think it considers dateAdjust*3600*1000 as a string. How do I fix that? I heard some people say to use parseInt(), but it doesn't work either.

```
  var date = new Date(new Date() + parseInt(dateAdjust*3600*1000) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please bear in mind that JavaScript operators doesn't work exactly as Google Sheets operators (mentioned because the question includes the google-sheets tag).

The fix might be to use `new Date().getTime()` or `new Date().toValue()`. This will return the date-time in milliseconds since `January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC`. Assuming that `dateAjust` has assigned a number, then the final code might be:

```
  var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + dateAdjust * 3600 * 1000 );
```

**Explanation**

In JavaScript, when using `+` having a Date object to the left, due to JavaScript rules, it's converted into a string. This happens because in JavaScript the `+` could make two possible operations, mathematical addition and string concatenation while `-` operator is only able to do a mathematical subtraction. This is a operation called type coercion.

Having a string to the left of `+`, makes the right operand to be converted into a string too.

Related

- [How to add days to Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/563406/1595451)
- [What exactly is Type Coercion in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19915688/1595451)
- [Why does Date return a date instead of the object's reference when referenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51395964/1595451)